# How to use ActionForm, ActionForward, DispatchAction, ActionMessages in Struts2

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

I am converting application from struts1 to struts2 so I need to use `ActionForm`, `ActionForward`, `DispatchAction`, `ActionMessages`. 
How I can use that in struts 2?

Comment: None of those exist in Struts 2.

Comment: What you really need is to 1) study Struts2, 2) rethink the application, and 3) drop 90% of the code, half of which will not even be replaced because not needed anymore (Struts2 has a much better signal-to-noise ratio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert an app from Struts 1 to Struts 2 then you don't need to use these classes because they belong to Struts 1, but if you want to use `struts2-struts1-plugin` then you can use them. Note that using this plugin is not easy and requires some effort to configure such application. See [Struts 1 Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/struts-1).